# How do keep my docker-compose running without exitiging with code 0

Tags: docker-compose

I'm doing my first Docker-Compose and I want the server to keep running in the local-host but its just exiting with code 0. I dont know why. This is my docker-compose.yml file. I would appreciate any help really new using docker.

```
> version: '3' 
> services:   
>   web:
>     build: .
>     ports:
>       - "5000:5000"
>   redis:
>     image: "redis:alpine"
```

[enter image description here][1]

**docker-redis-1  | 1:M 30 Nov 2021 01:28:44.357 * Ready to accept connections
docker-web-1 exited with code 0**

That is the error output im getting Code 0

My Dockerfile is as it follows

```
FROM python:3.4-alpine
ADD . /code  
WORKDIR /code  
RUN pip install-r requirements.txt  
CMD ["python", "webapp.py"]
```

Comment: How are you running the container?...To run in the BG use `docker-compose up -d` but note this will require `docker-compose stop` or `docker-compose down` run as a command to end the `up -d`...a 0 exit code means success so there is no error

Comment: I just tried it, and it keeps happening the same the docker-web keep exiting with code 0 and i nothing get display in my localhost

Comment: Then what is your start command? You can. See where things error for example using bash like: `docker-compose -f web logs`

Comment: Can you please edit your answer and add your Dockerfile, which should be found in the same directory?

Comment: To start im using docker-compose up -d as you mentioned. But keep having the same poroblem the server jsut exits and doens't stay up.

Comment: Hey @JHOAMSEBASTIANMOLINAGARCIA these guys don't know what they're talking about, it's not your docker-compose that's failing, it's likely in your Build, and an issue with your Dockerfile. Im looking at the docs you're following here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/

Comment: Thank you! I was following a video but it seems to be outdated. My Dockerfile must be different! thank you

Comment: Happy to help, i added my comment as an answer for upvoting. :)

Comment: Can't upvote becuase i'm new but marked it as correct. Thank you a lot.

Comment: I upvoted your question, you will get enough points soon! Enjoy your adventure into the Developer world!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Dockerfile doesn't look correct can you please follow this documentation a little more carefully, and fully copy the dockerFile in.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM python:3.7-alpine
WORKDIR /code
ENV FLASK_APP=app.py
ENV FLASK_RUN_HOST=0.0.0.0
RUN apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev linux-headers
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
COPY . .
CMD ["flask", "run"]
```